# Filtering through an API with Axio & React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

My problem is simple but I am missing some part of this filtering process.
I am trying to set my component state to whatever value I am giving to my checkbox input and return my state only if the value matches my data array in the API after a click event.

Though it logs the data correctly in my Chrome Console but I’ve been trying hard to set my logged data into my component state and without any success…

My end goal is to :

Part 1- Output the correct data in my component state after a click event.

Part 2- Get the initial data after the input has been unchecked.

Part 3- Being able to output multiple datas if more than 1 checkbox is checked.

Part 1 Code

```
  handleFilterButtons = (event) => {
  var valueInput = event.target.value;
  var apiFilters = `https://backend.greatsaigon.com/api/v1/en/venues`;
  axios.get(apiFilters)
    .then( (response) =>{
      this.setState({
        result: response.data.filter((req) => {
          if (req.options.beauty.hair.treatment !== "0") {
            req.options.beauty.hair.treatment.filter((res) => {
              if (res === valueInput) {
                  console.log(req)
                }
              })
            } 
          })
        })      
    })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

Comment: It doesn't output anything If I do a return statement inside my filter callback method or maybe I'm not returning it properly. That's what I tried => if (res === valueInput){ return req} but didn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think the function you want to use here is filter. The return value inside a filter is a boolean, but you are using a filter inside another filter. However, you can use forEach and since you are able to console the values successfully, you can take this value and push it to a variable which can be added to your state.

```
axios.get(apiFilters)
    .then( (response) =>{

        let result=[];
          response.data.forEach((req) => {
          if (req.options.beauty.hair.treatment !== "0") {
            req.options.beauty.hair.treatment.forEach((res) => {
              if (res === valueInput) {
                  result.push(req);
                }
              })
            } 
          })
        this.setState({results:results});   
    })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you! Though I was wondering how do you get back to the previous state if I unchecked the checkbox ?

Comment: In that case, you will have to save your current state to a variable, parse through the api just like you did using forEach loop, and if it matches, remove the value from the variable(instead of the push) and then set the state again with the updated value.

Comment: I still don’t know how to get the initial state with your method though I believe it’s the right one. Would you mind to give me an example please ?